# How to set a UITableView indexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that switches dataSource depending on user selection.  When a new dataSource is loaded and the cells drawn, the indexPath remains the same; fr ex if user was looking at cells 100-120 and selects a new dataSource, cells 100-120 of the new source will be displayed.  I would like each dataSource to forget previous view information and start at indexPath 0,0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the scrollToRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Send YES if you want the scrolling to be visible / animated.